# Area of the asteroid

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

**Question**: Consider the asteroid represented by a curve C in $R^2$ with parameterisation $r(t) := (cos^3t, sin^3t)$ for $ 0 \le t \le 2\pi$. Find the area of the asteroid using an appropriate area formula.

**Doubt**: Why can't we use the formula $Area = 1/2\int_0^{2\pi}r^2(t)dt$ in this case. Why does the formula $Area = {1\over 2}\int_C xdy - ydx$ give a different result?

Comment: It would be helpful if you enough of your computations for the each of the two methods for readers to find what could have gone wrong.

Comment: That said, the formula $A = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^{2\pi} r(\theta)^2 d\theta$ really does require the parameter to be the angular coordinate $\theta$, and your notation seems to use $r$ to represent two different quantities.

Comment: Oh OK I mistakenly took $t$ to be the angle $\theta$ with the x - axis.